# Some doubts with Meteor server for sending Push notification to android

Tags: android, push-notification

I have some doubts with Meteor server? Whether will it send push notification like Google C2DM? I mean this server can send push notification whenever we are puling data to server or it will pushes in a periodic manner? How can this server identifies the devices? Is there any device token like C2DM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Meteor server will push the messages as soon as you add them to the queue. If the clients are waiting for a push message (they are connected) they will receive the message (almost) instantly.
You can't identify clients, Meteor works with queue names, so you should use an unique queue name for each device (like hashing unique device or user info) I don't know how C2DM works, so I don't know the differences.